# Why I can't edit .bashrc file in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, bashrc

When I do

```
vim .bashrc
```

and try to edit the file it gives following error.

```
Can't open linked file for editing
```

When I do

```
ls -la
```

it shows

```
.bashrc -> /home/likewise-open/company/user/dotfiles/.bashrc
```

When I try to cd into `dotfiles`, it says directory does not exist.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your .bashrc is just a link to some other place `.bashrc -> /home/likewise-open/company/user/dotfiles/.bashrc`.

This is not a normal attitude, so instead of using sudo or whatever you have to bring it back to its normal place.

```
sudo cp /home/likewise-open/company/user/dotfiles/.bashrc ~
```

Then now change ownership if it's not owned by you:

```
sudo chown your-username:your-username ~/.bashrc
```

Now ensure it has the correct permissions:

```
chmod 644 ~/.bashrc
```

But since you say this:

> When I try to cd into dotfiles, it says directory does not exist.

This means the `/home/likewise-open/company/user/dotfiles/.bashrc` file is not founded and had been deleted, so for that you get the message:

> Can't open linked file for editing

This means the link is point to non existing file thus a broken link.

So you get a default bashrc file from /etc/skell

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Comment: Unless it has a very strange configuration, they can do it without root. `~` is their, so they can delete the link (`rm .bashrc`) and then copy the enterprise skeleton: `cp /home/likewise-open/company/user/dotfiles/.bashrc ~`, which *must* be readable anyway.

Comment: @downvoter. so why downvote?

Answer (score 0):

If your dotfiles directory was deleted, meaning your bashrc points to a dir that does not exist try removing the destination before copying etc/skel/

```
cp --remove-destination /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Answer (score 0):

This command solved my problem

```
find . -xtype l -delete
```

A bit of explanation:

- `-xtype l` tests for links that are broken (it is the opposite of `-type`)
- `-delete` deletes the files directly, no need for further bothering with `xargs`  or `-exec`

Answer (score -1):

You need superuser permissions to edit the file.

To become the superuser, type in `sudo -s` then enter your password. After you log in, then try your command, and it will work.

Comment: I tried sudo -s vim .bashrc and entered password still it did not work

Comment: Try `echo "my edit" | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: -1, why should he need `sudo` to edit `~/.bashrc`? `~/.bashrc` is by default owned by the user.

Comment: `sudo chmod og=rw bash.bashrc` can change the owner of bashrc , assuming that the OP might've accidentally executed this , its just a matter of simplicity to execute the command as root